# how to get an array by joining two arrays values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have two arrays

```
$column_names=array[ 0=>'student_id', 1=>'college_name', 2=>'name' ]
```

and

```
$student_details=array[ 0=>array [
   0=>'1', 1=>'xxx', 2=>'aaa' ], 1=>array [
   0=>'2', 1=>'yyy', 2=>'bbb' ] ]
```

I want to get an out put array as below:

```
 $student_details=array[ 0=>array [
'student_id'=>'1', 'college_name'=>'xxx', 'name'=>'aaa' ], 1=>array [
'student_id'=>'2', 'college_name'=>'yyy', 'name'=>'bbb' ] ]
```

Please somebody help me out to get the above output.

Comment: what have you tried so far? and why didnt it meet your expectations?

Comment: You should post real code or do `var_dump()`'s or `print_r()`'s of the data. This pseudo code makes it hard to read and is impossible to test.

Comment: i tried array_push method inside for loop. but i did not get the proper output.

Comment: Welcome. `$column_names=array[..]` works?

Comment: $column_names=Array
(
    [0] => school_id
    [1] => admission_no

)                                                                                                                                 
$student_details=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 55
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 55
            
        )

) these are the two inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the array and use array_combine

```
$column_names= [ 0=>'student_id', 1=>'college_name', 2=>'name' ];

$student_details=[ 0=>[
   0=>'1', 1=>'xxx', 2=>'aaa' ], 1=>[
   0=>'2', 1=>'yyy', 2=>'bbb' ] ];

foreach($student_details as &$sub){
    $sub = array_combine($column_names, $sub);
}
var_dump($student_details);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["student_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["college_name"]=>
    string(3) "xxx"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "aaa"
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(3) {
    ["student_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["college_name"]=>
    string(3) "yyy"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "bbb"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/D9kCE

Comment: foreach($student_details as &$sub){
    $sub = array_combine($column_names, $sub);
}    ,THIS CODE WORKED PROPERLY , THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$column_names = [ 0=>'student_id', 1=>'college_name', 2=>'name' ];

$student_details = [ 
    0=>[0=>'1', 1=>'xxx', 2=>'aaa' ], 
    1=>[0=>'2', 1=>'yyy', 2=>'bbb' ] 
];
$new_array = [];
foreach($student_details as $k=>$val){
     $new_array[$k] =  array_combine($column_names, $val);
}

print_r($new_array);
```